# How to recover intersection times?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

When we use `intersections` library we can get all intersection positions by naming them. But how can we recover the corresponding intersection times on the "sort by" path ?

I know that the intersection times must be hidden somewhere in the code there because this is how Bézier curves works : first we find the time, and then we obtain the position of the point at the given time.

In the following mock code I'm looking how to define `intersection/times` style (or something similar) that allows me to recover the intersection times following the "sort by" path (that is named `arc` in this case). And then I want to use them to decorate this same path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}
\tikzset{
  intersection/times/.code={
    \def\a{.25} % <- mock value
    \def\b{.75} % <- mock value
  },
  test mark/.style 2 args={ % <- mark two posions on the path
    decoration={ markings,
      mark =at position #1 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (1,0);},
      mark =at position #2 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (-1,0);}
    }, decorate
  },
  dot/.style={insert path={node[inner sep=1pt,circle,fill=red]{}}}
}
\def\testpath{(1,0) arc(270:90:1cm)}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[red, name path=arc] \testpath;
    \draw[blue, densely dotted, name path=line] (0,0) -- (1,1) --(0,2);
    \draw[
        name intersections={
          of=arc and line, sort by=arc,
          by={a,b},
          times={\a,\b} % <- this is a mock style that recover the intersection times
        },
        test mark={\a}{\b} % <- mark at the intersection times
      ] \testpath (a)[dot] (b)[dot]; % <- mark at the intersection positions
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a very first version of a real answer to the original question you have, still ugly since it uses `\pgfextra`. (The macro you are looking for is `\pgfintersectiongetsolutiontimes`, I think, and it can be found in `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex` together with a mini docu.)

However, from the comments I think what you really want to achieve can already be done with the `fillbetween` library of *pgfplots* (*not* Ti*k*Z). I illustrate this below where I produce your desired output with this method (and color the corresponding segment in blue for illustration). I still think your question is very interesting, ultimately it would be great if one could have all these features without loading pgfplots. However, looking at the complexity of the `fillbetween` library, one may suspect that the answer won't be a one-liner. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %<-added
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} %<-added
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<-added

\tikzset{
  intersection/times/.code={
    \def\a{.25} % <- mock value
    \def\b{.75} % <- mock value
  },
  test mark/.style 2 args={ % <- mark two posions on the path
    decoration={ markings,
      mark =at position #1 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (1,0);},
      mark =at position #2 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (-1,0);}
    }, decorate
  },
  dot/.style={insert path={node[inner sep=1pt,circle,fill=red]{}}}
}
\def\testpath{(1,0) arc(270:90:1cm)}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[red, name path=arc] \testpath;
    \draw[blue, densely dotted, name path=line] (0,0) -- (1,1) --(0,2);
    \path[
        name intersections={
          of=arc and line, sort by=arc,
          by={a,b},
          total=\Nint
        },
      ]       
      \pgfextra{\typeout{number\space of\space intersections:\space \Nint}
      \pgfintersectiongetsolutiontimes{1}{\tmp}{\dummy}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\tmp/2}
      \pgfintersectiongetsolutiontimes{2}{\tmp}{\dummyTwo}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\tmp/2}
      \typeout{\a,\b,\dummy}}
      \testpath (a)[dot] (b)[dot]; % <- mark at the intersection positions

   % desired output with fillbetween library      
   \path [draw,blue,
    name path=middle arc,
    intersection segments={
        of=arc and line,
        sequence={A1}
    },
    postaction={test mark={0}{1}}];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes `\pgfintersectiongetsolutiontimes` looks to be the begining ot the answer. Thanks. But looking in the comments of `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex` it can return numbers bigger than `1`, for example `1.5` means that it is in the middle of the second segment. Here it is coincidence that there are exactly 2 segments of exactly the same length so dividing by two give the exact answer. In general this parameter should be converted in length and this length is ok for decorations.

Comment: My idea is to be able to do all sort of things between intersection points : path replacing, path saving, path morphing, ... But probably `\pgfintersectiongetsolutiontimes` is enough. Some general decoration can be used to convert this index to path length by summing  `\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength`. And then to time by dividing by`\pgfdecoratedpathlength`. Do not waist your time on this question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kpym As for path replacing, path saving, path morphing : this can be all done conveniently with the *pgfplots* library fillbetween. And I think it is an interesting question, so I do not think it is a waste of time. ;-)

Comment: Really ? You learn me something : we can use `fillbetween` to recover part of a general path between two intersection points and then reuse it to do something else ?

Comment: @Kpym Yes, I modified my answer accordingly. Nevertheless it is a really good question. Maybe one can avoid having to load the fillbetween library. However, I guess that the code there is much better than my crappy `\pgfextra` stuff.