# Draw tangent of an arbitrary curve at intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I have this picture:

> [image]

and I want to draw a tangent line at each of the marked intersections. I have found some answers (and examples in the Ti*k*Z manual) using the `decorations.markings` library. The thing is that (from what I understood) this library only knows the tangent of a curve given the `position`, from 0 to 1, so I'd have to guess where, in the length of the curve, the intersection is, but I'd rather do that automagically :)

I thought about mapping the coordinate of the intersection to a normalised `[0, 1]` value, but I couldn't figure out how to do that either.

Code for the picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0.2) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,-0.75) .. (1,0.2) coordinate (LP1);
  \draw [xshift=1cm, blue, name path=eta]
    (0, 0.3) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,0) .. (1.0,-0.4)
             .. controls ++(0.3,0)    and ++(-0.3,0) .. (1.6, 0.3) coordinate (LP2);
  \draw [gray, name path=eta0] (LP1) -- (LP1-|LP2);
  \draw [red, name intersections={of=eta and eta0,total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{ (intersection-\s) circle (1pt) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

<sub>I think that this problem is fairly common, but I browsed plenty of intersections/tangents/markings questions but couldn't find what I'm trying to do, so sorry if it is a duplicate.</sub>

Comment: Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432541/121799 ?

Comment: Have you seen this question and its answers? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461573/138900

Comment: Additionally maybe helpful: [Tangent Lines Diagram Along Smooth Curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461573/tangent-lines-diagram-along-smooth-curve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possible way. If you do not want to load pgfplots, I am afraid it will be considerably more effort.

How does this proposal work?

1. The `pgplots` (!) library `fillbetween` allows us to decompose paths into intersection segments. These are called `A1` and `A2` in the examples below, and can be reversed, if needed.
2. Once we have such an intersection segment, the problem boils down to attaching tangents at the ends of these segments, which is a long-solved problem, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/121799).

These codes illustrate this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent at/.style={% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940
    decoration={ markings,
      mark =at position #1 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (0.5,0);},
    }, decorate
  }]

  \draw (0, 0.2) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,-0.75) .. (1,0.2) coordinate (LP1);
  \draw [xshift=1cm, blue, name path=eta]
    (0, 0.3) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,0) .. (1.0,-0.4)
             .. controls ++(0.3,0)    and ++(-0.3,0) .. (1.6, 0.3) coordinate (LP2);
  \draw [gray, name path=eta0] (LP1) -- (LP1-|LP2);
  \draw [red, name intersections={of=eta and eta0,total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{ (intersection-\s) circle (1pt) };
  \path [%draw,blue,
    name path=middle arc,
    intersection segments={
        of=eta and eta0,
        sequence={A1}
    },
    postaction={tangent at/.list={0,1}}];   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can do that with more intersections, too. You only need to add the tangents at the appropriate intersection segments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent at/.style={% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940
    decoration={ markings,
      mark =at position #1 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (0.5,0);},
    }, decorate
  }]

  \draw (0, 0.2) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,-0.75) .. (1,0.2)
  coordinate (LP1);
  \draw [xshift=1cm, blue, name path=eta]
    (0, 0.3) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,0) .. (1.0,-0.4)
             .. controls ++(0.3,0)    and ++(-0.3,0) .. (1.6, 0.3) 
   .. controls ++(0.6,0) and ++(-0.6,0) .. (2.8,-0.3) coordinate (LP2);
  \draw [gray, name path=eta0] (LP1) -- (LP1-|LP2);
  \draw [red, name intersections={of=eta and eta0,total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{ (intersection-\s) circle (1pt) };
  \path [%draw,red,thick,
    intersection segments={
        of=eta and eta0,
        sequence={A1}
    },
    postaction={tangent at/.list={0,1}}];   
  \path [%draw,green,thick,
    intersection segments={
        of=eta and eta0,
        sequence={A2}
    },
    postaction={tangent at/.list={1}}]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this can be automatized.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent at/.style={% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940
    decoration={ markings,
      mark =at position #1 with {\draw[purple,-latex](0,0) -- (0.5,0);},
    }, decorate
  }]

  \draw (0, 0.2) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,-0.75) .. (1,0.2)
  coordinate (LP1);
  \draw [xshift=1cm, blue, name path=eta]
    (0, 0.3) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,0) .. (1.0,-0.4)
             .. controls ++(0.3,0)    and ++(-0.3,0) .. (1.6, 0.3) 
   .. controls ++(0.6,0) and ++(-0.6,0) .. (2.8,-0.3) coordinate (LP2);
  \draw [gray, name path=eta0] (LP1) -- (LP1-|LP2);
  \draw [red, name intersections={of=eta and eta0,total=\t},
  /utils/exec={\xdef\NumIntersection{\t}}]
    \foreach \s  in {1,...,\t}{ 
    (intersection-\s) circle (1pt) };
  \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {1,...,\NumIntersection}    
  {
  \path [%draw,red,thick,
    intersection segments={
        of=eta and eta0,
        sequence={A\Y}
    },
    postaction={tangent at=1}];   
  } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Same result as above.)

Comment: Excellent! I was trying (and failing) to understand the link you posted in the comments when you answered. `pgfplots` won't be a problem at all. I hate to be the “just do this one more thing” user but, how do I add the intersection to an arbitrary number of intersections? For example, if I add `.. controls ++(0.6,0) and ++(-0.6,0) .. (2.8,-0.3)` to the end of the blue curve (before `coordinate`). I tried the `tangent at/.list` thingy, but apparently it doesn't do what I thought it did :/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No problem! I added an explanation (which I should have done right away...), and added the example you suggested.

Comment: Ooh, now I got it. I completely overlooked the `sequence` thing. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I added a slightly more automatized version.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines*[step=.5](0,-1)(3,1)
% curves
\tzbezier+(0, 0.2)(0.5,0.75)(-0.5,-0.75)(1,0)<coordinate (LP1)>
\draw [xshift=1cm, blue, name path=eta]
(0, 0.3) .. controls ++(0.5,0.75) and ++(-0.5,0) .. (1.0,-0.4)
         .. controls ++(0.3,0)    and ++(-0.3,0) .. (1.6, 0.3) coordinate (LP2);
\tzline[gray]"eta0"(LP1)(LP1-|LP2)
% intersections
\tzXpoint{eta}{eta0}(K)
\tzdots[red](K-1)(K-2);
% tangent
\tztangent[densely dotted]{eta}(K-1)[1.2:1.9]
\tztangent[densely dotted]{eta}(K-2)[2.2:2.6]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice package ;-)  Thank you!